# VLookup range in another worksheet dynamically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to use a function that will allow me to import a range from a previous worksheet.  I am not sure that my current macro allows this.  I can call the previous worksheet manually, but not with the function that I have.

Here is the function that works fine when I manually input the worksheet name:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,Aug9Daily!$D$3:$F$50,3, FALSE),"")
```

Here is the function that I am attempting to use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,NextSheetName()$D$3:$F$50,3, FALSE),"")
```

This is the VBA that I am using for the NextSheetName macro:

```
Function NextSheetName(Optional WS As Worksheet = Nothing) As String
    Application.Volatile True
    Dim S As String
    Dim Q As String
    If IsObject(Application.Caller) = True Then
        Set WS = Application.Caller.Worksheet
        If WS.Index = WS.Parent.Sheets.Count Then
            With Application.Caller.Worksheet.Parent.Worksheets
                Set WS = .Item(1)
            End With
        Else 
            Set WS = WS.Next
        End If
        If InStr(1, WS.Name, " ", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            Q = "'"
        Else
            Q = vbNullString
        End If
    Else
        If WS Is Nothing Then
           Set WS = ActiveSheet
        End If
        If WS.Index = WS.Parent.Worksheets.Count Then
            With WS.Parent.Worksheets
               Set WS = .Item(1)
            End With
        Else
            Set WS = WS.Next
        End If
        Q = vbNullString
    End If
    NextSheetName = Q & WS.Name & Q
End Function
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to select a range from another worksheet dynamically?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: If I enter it as I have above, it says the formula you typed contains an error.  If I enter the range inside the quotes, NextSheetName($D$3:$F$50),3,FALSE), I get a blank cell (not supposed to be blank)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to see if it works for you to fix your function's output:

```
NextSheetName =  Q & WS.Name & Q & "!"
```

And then you will need to concatinate the output inside of an indirect function like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,INDIRECT(NextSheetName() & "$D$3:$F$50"),3, FALSE),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this little UDF to be handy:

```
Function sheet_offset(rng As Range, i As Integer) As Range
    Application.Volatile 'necessary since value can change even when values of parameters do not
    Set sheet_offset = rng.Worksheet.Parent.Worksheets.Item(rng.Worksheet.Index + i).Range(rng.Address)
End Function
```

which offsets rng by i sheets - eg, i=0 means the same sheet, i=-1 means the previous sheet, and i=1 means the next sheet.

In your example, you'd use:

```
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D3,sheet_offset($D$3:$F$50,1),3, FALSE),"")
```

which would offset the range to reference the next worksheet.

Note that to make references relative to the current sheet (like yours) you would not specify the worksheet.  To make absolute references, just specify a worksheet in the reference (eg 'Sheet1'!$D$3:$F$50) and that becomes your origin (the sheet referenced when i=0)